# How to stop rsyslog output timestamp?

Tags: rsyslog

In my Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.2, the default `rsyslog` output is like the follow

```
Aug 12 18:35:32 xxxxxx : xxxxx
```

Now I don't like the timestamp `Aug 12 18:35:32` because I'm using the `golang` for logging. How can I configure `rsyslog` so that it won't add timestamp to the output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add in global section of your `/etc/rsyslog.conf`

```
$template noTimestampFormat,"%HOSTNAME% %syslogtag% %msg%\n"
$ActionFileDefaultTemplate noTimestampFormat
```

Also `man rsyslog.conf`