# Rsyslogd - remove timestamp on certain logs

Tags: linux, logs, rsyslog, rsyslogd

I'm trying to achieve the questioned [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/302972/how-to-stop-rsyslog-output-timestamp), but I need to discard the timestamp only on a specific log file. I.e. only `/var/log/mylog.log` should have no timestamps.

Is that possible with rsyslogd?

Comment: You might get more answers and get people viewing your question explaining the question by your own words. I might follow an accessory link to get extra data, but sure I am not following any random link just to find out what your question is about. People are also encouraged to not depend so much in links, as they might die somewhere in time.

Comment: Yes it is possible. Update your question with the current  action line you are using to log to that file.