# How to stop rsyslog output TIMESTAMP

Tags: date, time, rsyslog, delete

[this same question has already received a solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/302972/how-to-stop-rsyslog-output-timestamp?newreg=0cc33a0966e9481bb5439f827b97aa84) but it doesn't work

I'm looking for exactly this, I apply it in my rsyslog but it doesn't work for me, I restart my rsyslog, and nothing, I restart my operating system and there were no changes either.

@shintaroid asked the same question and got an answer but it doesn't seem to work for me.

I read somewhere that this from the TIMESTAMP is hard-coded at the rsyslog source code level.

Does anyone have a solution for this?
Has anyone made it work without the TIMESTAMP?

Comment: The order of directives matter, so if you add the template definition after the logging is done, nothing would happen. Can you add your ryslog.conf file here?

Comment: Thank you @Haxiel your info spark my mind to resolve this, am  reading manual pages and documentation for make it run. it's almost done.

Comment: my host is runing freebsd jails, one jail is rsyslog server, other jails are webservers that sends their logs.                                                                                <[SERVER]>
$ModLoad imtcp
$InputTCPServerRun 514
$template myFormat,"%msg%\n"
*.*         /var/log/messages;myFormat

<[REMOTE]>
$ModLoad imfile
global(workDirectory="/var/spool/rsyslog")
$InputFileName /var/log/nginx/access.log
$InputFileTag nginx:
$InputRunFileMonitor
@@192.168.0.250:514

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Haxiel 'cause his comment spin up my research on rsyslog.conf man page and online documentation from [official rsyslog site](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/)

my whole setup is a host running FreeBSD jails, one jail is rsyslog server, other jails are *'remote'* web servers that sends their logs via tcp. everything inside one box/machine. host runs firewall that connect  inter-jails communication and filters traffic as internet gateway.

```
<[SERVER]> 
$ModLoad imtcp 
$InputTCPServerRun 514 
$template myFormat,"%msg%\n" *.* /var/log/messages;myFormat 

<[REMOTE]> 
$ModLoad imfile 
global(workDirectory="/var/spool/rsyslog") 
$InputFileName /var/log/nginx/access.log 
$InputFileTag nginx: 
$InputRunFileMonitor
```